# Android Send data in the background when connected

Tags: android, service

Basicly I need that my app sends some data to a server when the connection to the network is established and it has to be in the background. That's it.

Is there a way that my service is automaticly started when connection is made?  Or should I use regular Service which tests the connection and run this service in something like 30min intervals? Should I use something like the AlarmManager to check for the connection? This seems as a waste of the resources and as far as I'm aware Android can stop services if resources are needed.

Any suggestions or even better - samples on what is the optimal way?

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a `broadcast receiver` for this purpose. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633704/in-android-to-check-the-internet-connection-is-available-for-frequently) question on SO.

You can check if internet connection has been established, there is no need to check after regular intervals.

(Quoting from the link I have mentioned earlier)

```
<receiver android:name=".ReceiverName" >
    <intent-filter >
        <action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE" />
        <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And

```
public class ReceiverName extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ConnectivityManager cm = ((ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE));
        if (cm == null)
            return;
        if (cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {
            // Send here
        } else {
            // Do nothing or notify user somehow
        }

    }
}
```

Hope this helps!